# AudioKit: hard pan can still be heard in both ears

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audiokit

If I have this setup, I can still hear the tone in the right ear even though I have a hard pan of `-1`.

This is the relevant code I have:

```
oscillator.start()
leftPan = AKPanner(oscillator, pan: -1)
leftPan.start()
AudioKit.output = leftPan
AudioKit.start()
```

How can I make a hard pan actually be only heard in the specified ear?

Comment: The code works for me, but maybe you should only start the oscillator after AudioKit starts.  Again, you don't need to start the leftPan.